# Product rule in gauge theory

Tags: gauge-theory

Source:

Chapter 11 of Freedman and Van Proeyen’s supergravity [textbook](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/physics/theoretical-physics-and-mathematical-physics/supergravity?localeText=United%20Kingdom&locale=en_GB&remember_me=on)

---

An infinitesimal symmetry transformation is determined by

1) a parameter, call it $\epsilon^A$, and

2) an operation, call it $\delta_\epsilon$.

The operation $\delta_\epsilon$

1) depends linearly on the parameter $\epsilon^A$, and

2) acts on fields, i.e. $\delta_\epsilon(\phi^i)$.

Let's consider a local symmetry, where the parameters $\epsilon^A$ are arbitrary functions of spacetime, $\epsilon^A(x).$

Another way to say that "$\delta_\epsilon$ depends linearly on the parameter $\epsilon^A$,'' is to write 
$$\delta_\epsilon \phi^i(x)=\epsilon^A T_A \phi^i$$

where the $T_A$ are operators on the space of fields and describe the symmetry transformation with the parameter stripped.

---

I'm having trouble understanding the following line, which is meant to show that the normal derivative is not covariant ("A covariant quantity is a local function that transforms under all local symmetries with no derivatives of a transformation parameter.")

$$ \delta_\epsilon \partial_\mu \phi^i = \epsilon^A \partial_\mu (T_A\phi^i) + (\partial_\mu \epsilon^A) T_A \phi^i$$

It seems this is the product rule? I can't place it.

Comment: This just says that $\delta_\epsilon$ commutes with $\partial_\mu$, and then expands $\partial_\mu(\delta_\epsilon\phi^i)$ using the Leibniz rule.

Comment: And why can we switch the order of $\delta_\epsilon$ with $\partial_\mu$? Doing a symmetry transformation on a field then taking the derivative need not be the same as doing the symmetry transformation on the fields derivation, right?

Comment: It is the same for internal symmetries that only affect the field but not the spacetime coordinate. Which I implicitly assumed to be the case you are interested in.

Comment: Indeed, the field-space generator of the transformation $T_A$ acts on the fields $\phi^i$. This allows us to move from $\epsilon_1{}^A T_A(-\epsilon_2{}^B (t_B)^i{}_j \phi^j)$ to $-\epsilon_1{}^A \epsilon_2{}^B (t_B)^i{}_j T_A \phi^j$. But I don't see how that helps me in the case of the $\partial_\mu$. This is a function on the fields, not some number/matrix like the $\epsilon_2^B$ / $(t_b)^i{}_j$.